# Submit an image filename when clicked with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, forms

I'm attempting to create a page with Rails where it displays the images stored in a folder and when one is clicked it submits the image filename to a related form. While I have managed to display the images on a webpage I can't get submitting working at all.

My current source code is:

```
<% @fileArray.each do |x| %>
    <%= image_submit_tag(x, {:id => x, :action => "submitimage"}) %>
<% end %>
```

Where the fileArray is a list of all the image files in the directory and my submitimage action is currently defined as:

```
def submitimage
  redirect_to :controller => 'home', :action => "index"
end
```

Currently it doesn't seem to call the redirect function (which I will replace with code to pass a variable to the form hopefully).

I am fairly new to rails so I expect I'm missing a trick here but does anyone know the method for submitting actions when an image is clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`image_submit_tag` is useless without a form. As you have it, it's just a button. You'd be better off making it a link:

```
<%= link_to image_tag(x), submit_image_path(:filename => x) %>
```

And in your routes:

```
 match 'images/:filename/submit' => 'images#submit', :as => :submit_image
```

And in your controller:

```
def submit
  @image = Image.create(:filename => params[:filename]) # or whatever
end
```

**edit** I should point out that this would be better constructed using resourceful routes, but I will leave that up to you. You can read all about it [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Comment: Ah that makes sense, I thought there was something iffy about image_submit_tag.I'll have a look at resourceful routes now as well. Thanks for the help!